# How to update view in SwiftUI after sending data to server without "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior" error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I make a POST request to my server via the createJob function in JobViewModel. The associated job is being created in my database, however, the CreateOfferView does not update as intended (once "Create job" button is being clicked) and I get the error / warning "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

Am I updating state in CreateOfferView correctly?

Note: I am aware that the variable "viewStatus" should not be of type String.

ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

struct JobRequestBody: Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let time: Date
    let location: String
    let userId: User
}
 
class JobViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    var userId: String
    var token: String
    
    @Published var jobs: [JobOffer]?
    
    // MARK: - FUNCTIONS
    
    init(userId: String, token: String) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.token = token
    }
    
    func createJob(title: String, description: String, time: Date, location: String, owner: User, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:4000/api/jobs") else {
            return
        }

        let body = JobRequestBody(title: title, description: description, time: time, location: location, userId: owner)

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(true)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CreateOfferView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var time = Date()
    @State private var location = ""
    @State private var description = ""
    @State private var viewStatus = "notCreated"
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var jobViewModel: JobViewModel
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewStatus == "notCreated" {
            createJobBody
        } else if viewStatus == "loading" {
            loadingBody
        } else {
            createdBody
        }
    }
    
    var loadingBody: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressView()
                .scaleEffect(2)
        }
        .padding(25)
    }
    
    var createdBody: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            Text("Congrats! You have successfully created a new job.")
        }
        .padding(25)
    }
    
    var createJobBody: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SecondaryTextFieldView(placeholderSymbol: "pencil.circle.fill", placeholderText: "Title", content: $title)
                DatePicker(selection: $time, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("\(Image(systemName: "calendar.circle.fill")) Time")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .accentColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 25)
                SecondaryTextFieldView(placeholderSymbol: "mappin.circle.fill", placeholderText: "Location", content: $location)
                MultiLineTextFieldView(placeholderSymbol: "line.3.horizontal.circle.fill", placeholderText: "Description", content: $description)
                Spacer()
                SecondaryButton(symbol: "plus.circle.fill", title: "Create job") {
                    viewStatus = "loading"
                    
                    let user = userViewModel.authData?.loggedInUser
                    
                    if let owner = user {
                        jobViewModel.createJob(title: title, description: description, time: time, location: location, owner: owner) { success in

                            // Also tried not to wrap state update in DispatchQueue as I already do so in the ViewModel function
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                viewStatus = "created"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Suggest a job")
            .padding(25)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your button action should invoke a method in your view model. The completion should be in that function and it should update n `@Published` property of the view model. You can't update an `@State` property.

Comment: I think the button action invokes the createJob function of the jobViewModel where also the completion takes place. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more on your solution (especially on the part why @Published instead of @State)? Thank you!

Comment: The completion clearly takes place in the view, for example the line `viewStatus = "created"` would have generated a compilation error otherwise.

Comment: `@State` properties can only be modified by view operations (like binding it to a `TextField`.  By modifying state in the async dispatch you are updating the state during the view update, as the error says. If you set a published property then the actual change of the property will trigger the view update.

Comment: When you click on the button you update viewStatus = loading, which cause the CreateOfferView to be redrawn which will cause the list of your completion handler.

Comment: Try the new .task then you can remove the ObservableObject